# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions: You are missing Mute Members permission(s) to run this command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to program a command that mutes every member in the author's voice channel. I'm doing this so myself and my friends can mute ourselves when we swap to in-game voice chat automatically. But for reasons I cannot explain, I can never get it to work. Here's my code:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def mute(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        for member in channel.members:
            await member.edit(mute=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
```

This is the [full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXx8z.jpg)

I understand that the bot and the author need a mute members permission, but both of them do! I even made sure that they were at the top of the role list, and I edited the voice channel permissions to allow mute members for the author and bot. No matter what I do, I always keep getting the same error! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder it might be something about the bots having the general permission to mute a member in the server but not in that specific category?

Comment: I did give permissions for both the bot and the author to mute members on the server, voice channel, and the category the voice channel is in.

Comment: Do you have any checks on your command(s)? `MissingPermissions` is a `CheckFailure`.

Comment: Oh crap I do. My bad, I thought I included it in the code above. I changed it.

Comment: You might try using [`has_guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_guild_permissions) instead.  I suspect the channel permissions don't have `mute_members` because you can't mute people in a text channel.  You would have to check `channel.permissions_for(ctx.author)` in the body of your callback.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def has_channel_permissions(**kwargs):
    def predicate(ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is not None:
            if ctx.author.voice.channel is not None:
                if kwargs in dict(ctx.author.voice.channel.permissions_for(ctx.author)) and kwargs in dict(commands.user:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
        return False
    return commands.check(predicate)


@commands.command()
@has_channel_permissions(mute_members=True)
async def mute(self, ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for member in channel.members:
        await member.edit(mute=True)
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution and how this solves the problem?

Comment: @Skully first of all, using `if var:` to check if var isn't None is bad practice, you should always use `if var is not None:`, since if var is 0, False, etc. i.e. a "falsey" object, it will not run. second, the custom check is checking if the bot and user have permission to mute in the voice channel, as using has_permissions checks if the user has permissions to mute in the text channel, which obviously is not what we're looking for.